# How to change or get all keys using the maxkeys returned by the listbucket xml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to list all my files in my public bucket using the url http://gameexperiencesurvey.s3.amazonaws.com/
You can visit the url to see the xml.

The XML contains an element called MaxKeys with value 1000 which is the maximum number of keys returned in the response body. What if I want to list all the keys that I have, how do I do that?
Also, what is the max limit for number of keys and their size on on a free aws s3 account?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called S3 pagination. See: [Iterating Through Multi-Page Results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html)

**Iterating Through Multi-Page Results**

> As buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
>   complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
>   large result sets, the Amazon S3 API supports pagination to split them
>   into multiple responses. Each list keys response returns a page of up
>   to 1,000 keys with an indicator indicating if the response is
>   truncated. You send a series of list keys requests until you have
>   received all the keys. AWS SDK wrapper libraries provide the same
>   pagination.

You need to have **sufficient privileges** to list the object keys.

**AWS Free Tier for S3**

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to make a request like this work >> http://gameexperiencesurvey.s3.amazonaws.com/?MaxKeys=2000

Comment: @vipin8169 No, 1000 is the max. Even if you request 2000, only a max of 1000 is returned.